# Select-String does not work on log files

Tags: powershell

I have some logs where I  want to select some strings. I tried this on some tests notepad.txt files:

```
gci | Select-String -Pattern "Deleting" | group path | select name
```

and it worked perfectly fine. Now I want to do the same for our *.log file but nothing shows up on a screen. I can open a log file in notepad without problems. I noticed that if I run:

```
Get-Content myLog.log
```

it returns:

```
0 0 : 0 1 : 3 9 . 0 5 3 [ I N T E R N A L . T ( 3 5 4 ) ] >   D e l e t i n g   f i l e   ' \ \ l e v i a t a n \ b a i x e s \ O F F S U M A R I D A
```

What possibly can be wrong with these logs file that makes get-content to add so many spaces? Is there a way in PowerShell to remove all spaces? Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like your log file is UTF-16 encoded without a [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (BOM). Both `Select-String` and `Get-Content` default to ASCII/ANSI encoding unless a BOM indicates otherwise. You can override the detected/default encoding via the parameter `-Encoding`:

```
Get-ChildItem | Select-String -Pattern "Deleting" -Encoding unicode | ...
```